# How to create right relations between models in Django project

Tags: django

I am developing Django progect with following models:

```
class Aircraft_fleet(models.Model):
    Aircraft_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    Aircraft_Serial_Number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    Engine_1_Ser_Num = models.ForeignKey('Engine', related_name='Engine_1', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Engine_2_Ser_Num = models.ForeignKey('Engine', related_name='Engine_2', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

```
class Engine(models.Model):
    Ser_Num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Flight_Num = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    Flight_Date = models.DateField()
    Oil_Quantity_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Quantity_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

One Aircraft (Aircraft_fleet model) have two Engine Ser_Num (different of course). Particular Engine Ser_Num (Engine model) is fitted only on one partucular Aircraft.
The thing is that in database, "Engine" table has multiple records for each Engine "Ser_Num".
See picture below:
[Engine Model in database look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwADJ.jpg)

I can't determine how to create the proper relations between these two models.

Currently, relation is one to many, but it doesn't work. Following error apears:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'oilcons_aircraft_fleet' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: oilcons_aircraft_fleet.Engine
_2_Ser_Num_id contains a value '193262' that does not have a corresponding value in oilcons_engine.id.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if I understand you correctly the `engine_ser_num` does not belong to the `Aircraft_fleet` but to the `Engine`.

Go with this:

```py
class Aircraft_fleet(models.Model):
    Aircraft_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    Aircraft_Serial_Number = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Engine(models.Model):
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey('Aircraft_fleet', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Ser_Num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Flight_Num = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    Flight_Date = models.DateField()
    Oil_Quantity_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Quantity_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Now one `Engine` can be related to one `Aircraft_fleet`

```py
e = Engine.objects.all().first()
print(e.aircraft.Aircraft_type)
```

And one `Aircraft_fleet` can be related to multiple `Engine`s

```py
af = Aircraft_fleet.objects.all().first()
for engine in af.engine_set.all():
    print(engine.Ser_num)
```

Let me know how it goes.

#### important edit:

For sure you need to do the migrations correctly and migrate it. Because that `IntegrityError` could also be caused by "old" data inside the database that still have "old" relationships.

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked. All migrations have been run successfully.

Comment: However, when Engine be removed from one aircraft and installed to another aircraft, I will have to change ALL"aircraft"  cells for applicable engine. By the way, I will continue to develop my Django project and test how these model relations suit my project

Comment: That is not correct. You could easily switch one engine to another aircraft with doing: `engine.aircraft = <new aircraft_fleet instance>`

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain what is 'af.engine_set.all()'? What exactly "engine_set" property is? I tried to run this example of your code: ''' af = Aircraft_fleet.objects.all().first()
for engine in af.engine_set.all():
    print(engine.Ser_num) ''' but nothing happened

Comment: For some reason, it returns empty <QuerySet []> print(af.engine_set.all())

Comment: You'll find [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) more information about lookups. `Engine.aircraft` is an easy lookup and self explanatory. But getting the Engine when you have an Aircraft-object it is called reverse lookup. Because one Aircraft has multiple Engines the reverse lookup calls this a `_set` and returns a query set of all to that Aircraft related Engines. You can also run `af.engine_set.get()` and `af.engine_set.filter()` and all other queryset methods.

Answer (score 0):

possible structure:

```
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    Aircraft_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    Aircraft_Serial_Number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

aircraft may have 2/3/4 ...  engines:

```
class Engine(models.Model):
    Ser_Num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey('Aircraft', ....)   # engine belongs to an aircraft
    ...
```

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    Flight_Num = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    Flight_Date = models.DateField()
```

```
class EngineDataRecord(models.Model):
    flight = models.ForeignKey('Flight', ....)     # Engine Data record is for a certain flight
    engine = models.ForeignKey('Engine', ....)     # and a certain engine
    Oil_Quantity_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Quantity_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Departure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Oil_Temperature_Arrival = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```